# Planning for a BATCH Delete operation in SharePoint Hosted APP

Tags: sharepoint-hosted-app, soap, batch

I'm planning to use SOAP Services to do a batch **DELETE** operation in SharePoint Hosted APP. I'm searching for "**How to pass Site Url to SOAP services**" since the normal way won't work. I found no post regarding this.

Any other alternative ways of doing Batch Delete operation in REST API or JSOM ?

or any suggestions regarding the SOAP ?